# Does Unreal Engine 4 toolset support C++11 or C++14 on OS X / Clang?

Tags: unreal-engine4

I have some interest on UE4. Currently, I am developing a mobile game, and have a pretty large existing codebase written in C++11/14 with Clang.

AFAIK, UE4 is using a custom compiler (preprocessor? whatever), and that means C++ compatibility may differ on their own tools. How is the support for C++11/14 on UE4?

Comment: You might get better results asking this on http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ . I've not used that site, just seen it around so not able to guarantee that this is on topic there.

Comment: @Chris It seems to be… I will consider it. It's always ambiguous that finding a proper site for a question. I think SO need to do something on this hardness.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

UE4 supports C++11 [as stated in their **Coding standard**](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Programming/Development/CodingStandard/index.html#c++11andmodernlanguagesyntax)

and "`Unreal Engine is built to be massively portable to many C++ compilers`"
which means, it [builds](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Programming/Development/CompilingProjects/index.html#settingthebuildconfiguration) with the default compiler of Visual Studio or Xcode

Answer (score 1):

It also depends on the which version you are using, I mean for example, I tried https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Programming/Development/CodingStandard/index.html#strongly-typedenums but, it given me error saying like "Missing '{' in 'Enum'"

Ofcourse, their is a fix for this in October release 4.5.

Also note, C++11 not enabled for iOS, so standard features std::chrono, std::unique_ptr..  etc raise compilation errors. probably this month they are trying to release the fix for it.

Answer (score 1):

The C++14 seems to be officially supported as of now:

«We are using many C++14 language features that seem to be well-supported across modern compilers...»